Why do we integrate over the interior of the domain of dependence for the 1D wave equation with a source?
My question is about the wave equation on the infinite line with zero initial data and a source $F(x, t)$. The solution is:
$u(x, t)=\frac{1}{2 c} \int_0^t \int_{x-c(t-\tau)}^{x+c(t-\tau)} F\left(x^{\prime}, \tau\right) d x^{\prime} d \tau$
I understand how waves (and therefore the contributions from the source) propagate along the characteristic lines, and so anything outside the domain of dependence isn't going to have an effect at the point $(x_0, t_0)$. What I don't understand is why we integrate over the interior of the domain of dependence. For example, consider what the source is doing at $(x_0, 0)$ (the center of the base of the triangle that is the domain of dependence for $(x_0, t_0)$). The effect of that source is going to then propagate to the left and the right along the characteristic lines. These characteristic lines are never going to intersect with the point $(x_0, t_0)$, which I would think means that this disturbance at $(x_0, 0)$ isn't going to affect what happens at $(x_0, t_0)$. But clearly it does, since $F(x_0, 0)$ shows up in the expression for $u(x, t)$.
Where am I going wrong here?

The source affects the solution along the entire characteristic, hence the integral. Write out the characteristic equations and you will see

To understand what the issue is here, I think it's a good idea to first consider the wave equation without a source:
$$
u_{tt} = c^2 u_{xx}
.
$$
As you surely know, the general solution is
$$
u(x,t) = f(x+ct) + g(x-ct)
,
$$
and to solve an initial value problem, the single-variable functions $f$ and $g$ need to be determined such that they match the given initial data (at time $t=0$, say).
If the initial conditions consist of a given wave profile with zero velocity,
$$
u(x,0) = \phi(x)
,\qquad
u_t(x,0) = 0
,
$$
then $f(s) = g(s) = \frac12 \phi(s)$, and the wave just splits into two halves, one going off to the left and the other to the right:
$$
u(x,t) = \tfrac12 \phi(x+ct) + \tfrac12 \phi(x-ct)
.
$$
So in this case everything behaves in accordance with your intution.
However, if you instead have a zero wave profile with given initial velocity,
$$
u(x,0) = 0
,\qquad
u_t(x,0) = \psi(x)
,
$$
then (as you can check) we must take $f(s) = -g(s) = \frac{1}{2c} \Psi(s)$,
where $\Psi$ is some antiderivative of $\psi$,
leading to the solution
$$
u(x,t) = \tfrac{1}{2c} \Psi(x+ct) - \tfrac{1}{2c} \Psi(x-ct)
.
$$
(It doesn't matter which antiderivative you pick, since the arbitrary constant of integration cancels out here.)
In terms of the given function $\psi$, this can be written as
$$
u(x,t) = \frac{1}{2c} \int_{x-ct}^{x+ct} \psi(s) \, ds
.
$$
So even though the solution consists of waves travelling with speed $c$ exactly,
you see that the values of $\psi$ don't propagate in that simple way;
at the point $(x,t)$ you get a contribution from a whole interval on the $x$-axis, not just from two points.
For the wave equation with a source,
$$
u_{tt} = c^2 u_{xx} + F(x,t)
,
$$
things are very similar, since during an infinitesimal time interval $dt$
there will be an extra contribution $F(x,t) \, dt$ added on to $u_t$,
in addition to what you get from the term $c^2 u_{xx}$,
so that (by superposition) the solution will be as for the source-free wave equation
plus the “sum” (i.e., the integral over all earlier times) of the contributions consisting of solutions starting off from zero at an earlier time $t$ with a prescribed velocity $u_t(x,t) = F(x,t) \, dt$.
(This is Duhamel's principle.)
And as we saw above, such prescribed values for the velocity $u_t$ “propagate in triangles” rather than just along straight lines.
